# creating street lights in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create street lights in my environment box in opengl using c++. I need to create spot lights for this, I have written the code below but it does not work as a spot light. What am I doing wrong, or do you have any other solution for my problem?

```
GLfloat ambientLight[] = {0.7f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientLight); 
GLfloat directedLight[] = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};
GLfloat directedLightPos[] = {-10.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, directedLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, directedLightPos);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all of your light code you are missing some important lines. You only define ambient/diffuse light colors and a light position.

- You need to enable lighting with: `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)`
- You need to enable the light you are using: eg: `glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)`
- I am not sure but i think you also need to define a material ([glMaterial](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMaterial.xml)).
- You need to define the direction of your light: `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, direction);`

Two other notes:

- Make sure your normal vectors are set correct or you won't see a result
- If i remember correctly fixed function lighting only works for vertices and not for pixels. So if you have a light source above a single quad you won't see any light spot.

Comment: +1. Also: last element in position need to be non-zero for spotlight, and GL_SPOT_CUTOFF need to be less than 90 (default 180 for light0).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I edited my code as below, but the environment is still dark. What am I missing? glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); glEnable(GL_LIGHT0) ; GLfloat spotLightColour[] = {1.0,0.0,1.0}; GLfloat spotlightDirection[] = {0.0,-1.0,0.0}; GLfloat directedLightPos[] = {100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 10.0f}; glLightf(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,45); glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPOT_DIRECTION,spotlightDirection); glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, directedLightPos); glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPECULAR,spotLightColour); glLightf(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPOT_EXPONENT,120);

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in "new" opengl (core 3.+) there is no "lighting" support. All of those enums and functions are deprecated.

So you may want to look for some other solutions:

- [modern opengl tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/index.html)
- [opengl book](http://openglbook.com/)

Also it is worth saying that those "old" lighting functions were very ease to use and they have a lot of didactic advantages.